# Filter the post listing for a particular category from archive month list

Tags: archives, categories

I have the month year archive list in my sidebar. After clicking on any month, all posts on that month is listed.

Now I how can I filter the post listing for a particular category? What I mean is that what ever post I have in that category on that month will be listed after clicking on a month in archive list.

Answer (score -1):

You have a classic plugin for filtering on archive by category. Check out it and let's see if it does what you want.

[Archives for category WP plugin](http://kwebble.com/blog/2007_08_15/archives_for_a_category)